# How to reverse geocode PySpark dataframe? I have VehicleID, eventdatetime, latitude, longitude, vehicle speed columns and over a million rows

Tags: python, pyspark, geospatial, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I have `VehicleID`, `eventdatetime`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `vehicle speed` columns and over a million rows.
I need to fetch `city`, `state`, `district` for the same.

here is the working python code snippet for the same using geopy and reverse-geooder library. I am not able to do the same in pyspark.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Coordinates tuple.Can contain more than one pair.
    coordinates = list(zip(pdVehicles['gpsLatitude'],pdVehicles['gpslongitude']))#generates pairs of latlong
    data = reverseGeocode(coordinates)
    pdVehicles['City_Town'] = [i['name']for i in data]
    pdVehicles['State'] = [i['admin1'] for i in data]
    pdVehicles['District'] = [i['admin2'] for i in data]
```

I tried using UDF but it didn't work.

Comment: how did your udf look like?

Comment: https://github.com/aayushs7ha/Pyspark-Tutorial/blob/main/Pyspark_reverseGeocode.py

Comment: UDFs return a single column, not multiple columns. so, try to return your values as an array or struct, and then create 3 columns using that result

Comment: Give us a sample input and output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099762/python-reverse-geocoding-to-get-city-name-and-state-name-in-pandas   -> I need to do the same with PySpark